# Interface Builder UIImageView not showing image, only black screen

Tags: interface-builder, ipad

I have a UIView in Interface Builder and set up different UIImageViews for the background images that I want displayed that are not going to move at all (thus I didn't think I needed IBOutlets for them).

However, when the view is loaded on the iPad, it shows a black screen, and none of the images are shown.

Does something need to be set in Interface Builder to show the images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you add the image to the Resources folder, you have to make sure that you check the correct target. In your case check the iPad target. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use IBOutlets to do this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug while using cocoa pods. The pod included a Default.png file that was being selected in interface builder over the file with the same name in the regular project.